# ScriptEngine JavaScript Doesn't Support Contains?

Tags: javascript, java, javax

I've got some code like the following.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval("[1, 2, 3].contains(1)");
```

But that throws the following error

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: [1, 2, 3].contains is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

I can do indexOf(1) instead and that seems to work, but is there a reason why I don't have access to contains with this parser?

Comment: javascript indeed does not include a `array.contains` method. You can try `array.includes(item)`, or `array.indexOf(item) !== -1`

Comment: Because there is no `Array::contains` in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Your code would be:

```
engine.eval("[1, 2, 3].includes(1)");
```